# rounding float up $.01 in python

Tags: python, floating-point, currency, rounding

I am working on a program that stores numbers as floats which I eventually write to a file as currency.  I am currently using the round() function to round it to 2 decimals, but the business area would like me to round to the next penny no matter what the third decimal is.  For example:

```
x = 39.142
```

In this case I am trying to get x to round up to 39.15.  Obviously when I do the round function I get 39.14...

```
>>> round(x, 2)
    39.14
```

Is there a way I can always round up to the next penny?  I should mention that the numbers I am dealing with are printed to the file as currency.

Comment: If it's currency, please don't work with floats. It's just asking for trouble. It can be done, of course, but it's more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: @LanceCollins: The answer that you have selected is grossly wrong. See my comments.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using the [decimal module](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html):

```
import decimal
D = decimal.Decimal
cent = D('0.01')

x = D('39.142')
print(x.quantize(cent,rounding=decimal.ROUND_UP))
# 39.15
```

Decimals have many options for rounding. The options and their meanings can be found [here](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html#decimal.Context).

Comment: +1 This should be the accepted answer. Tim's should be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to write it in cents, you could use int(x*100+.5) to get cents integer from float dollars.

Answer (score 0):

Very late to this, but in case anyone wants a simple one-liner in Python 3:

```py
import math

x_rounded = math.ceil(x*100) / 100
```